# Python: Is it possible to override/extend an instance method of one class when it is used in another class?

Tags: python, class, methods, overriding, instance

I'm planning out a Python project. I'm going to have classes that use instances of other classes. Is it possible to override/extend a method from within another class, like this:

```
class Foo:

    a = Bar()
    b = Bar()
    c = Bar()

class Baz:

    x = Bar()
    y = Bar()
    z = Bar()

class Qux:

    p = Bar()
    q = Bar()
    r = Bar()

class Bar:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_something():
        # Thing to do

Baz.x.do_something() # Does the same thing 
Qux.p.do_something() # Does the same thing

Foo.a.do_something() # Does something slightly different
```

The slightly different behaviour is going to depend on the Foo class instance so I can't create a new method for it in the Bar class.
NB Most of the behaviours of Bar will be the same. I just want to do an extra step in the Foo.a.do_something()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a clean way. In overall this seems like a bad idea. How will you know when `do_something` behaves how? It's gonna be a debugging nightmare.

If `do_something` needs to do something different, subclass `Bar` and implement it differently in each subclass.

```
class Bar:    
    def do_something():
        # Does something

class Bar2(Bar):    
    def do_something():
        # Does something else
```

Comment: Thanks. It felt like a bad idea, you are right. I just couldn't think how else to do it. I'll give your suggestion a shot. Thank you!